# rails architecture/best practice question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture

i have been brainstorming the best way to do this, and figured i should reach out to the community for some ideas/clarity.

basically from a single payment controller, i want to be able to handle various payment options that a user might select.  for example, my controller gets hit with a post request with `:payment_option => paypal`.  i want to pass off logic to handle the paypal specific operations, then hand back to the controller a url (to paypal) to redirect to.

i was doing a `params[:payment_option].constantize` to initialize a Paypal class, but the problem i ran into was not able to access various pieces of data that paypal requires (ie current user information, request IP address, cookie data, url helpers, etc.)

then i thought maybe i could have a paypal module, but how to include the correct payment module programmatically?  and it seemed that i might be mis-using the module concept because i would be using the module for specific logic, rather than shared logic.

so if the user instead chooses google checkout, the controller regardless of payment method, should only need generic instructions

take params[:payment_option]
get the payment_option_url
receive payment_option_response

any thoughts on a good approach to doing something like this?  i have run into similar scenarios in the past, but was never to sure it was the best route.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Payment                                                                
  def self.handle                                                            
    raise 'must impliment in subclass'                                       
  end                                                                        
end                                                                          

class PaypalPayment < Payment                                                
end                                                                          

class GooglePayment < Payment                                                
end                                                                          

class PaymentController < ApplicationController                              
  def show_me_the_money                                                      
    case params[:payment_option]                                             
    when 'paypal': url = PaypalPayment.handle params                         
    when 'google': url = GooglePayment.handle params                         
    end      

    redirect_to url                                                                   
  end                                                                                 
end
```